# How to update android apk file name on build.gradle file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I want to change the android output apk build file name. 
Below is my **build.gradle** file.

```
buildTypes {
    release {

        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.Go2NurseAndroid

    }
    debug{
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            renameAPK(variant, defaultConfig, 'T')
        }
    }

    production {

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            renameAPK(variant, defaultConfig, 'R')
        }
    }
}

def renameAPK(variant, defaultConfig, buildType) {
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
    def formattedDate = new Date().format('yyMMdd')

    def file = output.packageApplication.outputFile
    def fileName = 'Go2Nurse' + "_V" + defaultConfig.versionCode + "_" + formattedDate + "_" + buildType + ".apk"
    output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)

    }
}
```

After I run gradle build command, I got below apk file generated:

```
$ find . -name '*.apk'
./app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
./app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk
./app/build/outputs/apk/Go2Nurse_V2_160805_R.apk
```

I wander why there are three apk file generated and only one apk file's name was changed by my configuration. The other two app-debug.apk and app-release.apk didn't change. Which one should I use for production?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do check if these aren't the old files

1. `/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk`,
2. `/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk`

In your app level gradle file.

```
android {
       .....
       ...
       ..

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(
                        output.outputFile.parent,
                        output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "version_name.apk"))
            }
        }
}
```

I use this to add version name like **app-debug-v16.apk**

As for your question **"only one apk file's name was changed"**. All the apk file names were changed in my case.